# Difference between a binomial experiment and a Bernoulli Trial?

Tags: statistics, intuition, binomial-distribution

I'm studying in an introductory statistics textbook and it's confusing me when it mentioned this:

> "Any experiment that has characteristics two and three and where n= 1
>   is called a Bernoulli Trial(named after Jacob Bernoulli who, in the
>   late 1600s studied them extensively). A binomial experiment takes
>   place when the number of successes is counted in one or more Bernoulli
>   Trials."

Comment: A binomial experiment consists of a sequence of Bernoulli trials. For example, a single coin flip is a Bernoulli trial. 100 independent coin flips with the same coin is a binomial experiment.

Answer (score 1):

You flip a coin. X is the random variable "The outcome of the coin flip", which can be H or T. X is a Bernoulli random variable which, if the coin is fair, has P(X = H) = 0.5 and P(X = T) = 0.5.

Now consider flipping the coin 10 times. Let us say that Y is the random variable "The number of heads out of ten coin flips". Now Y can take any of the values 0 to 10 inclusive. It is a Binomial random variable and quite different from a Bernoulli variable. It then makes sense to calculate the 11 probabilities P(Y = 0), P(Y = 1),...,P(Y = 10).

When considering probability questions, and before you start to calculate anything, you should always try and write down exactly what your variable is e.g. X = "The outcome when I flip a coin once", Y = "The number of heads out of 10" etc.